# Is there any way to broadcast a part of your screen as webcam on OSX (for twitch, omegle etc)?

Tags: macos, webcam

Title: can you get a section of your screen recognised as if it was a webcam, so sites like twitch and omegle will read from it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use OBS, also known as Open Broadcaster Software.

Here's the [official site](https://obsproject.com/)'s description of OBS:

> Open Broadcaster Software is free and open source software for video recording and live streaming. Supported features include:
>
> - Encoding using H264 (x264) and AAC.
> - Support for Intel Quick Sync Video (QSV) and NVENC.
> - Unlimited number of scenes and sources.
> - Live RTMP streaming to Twitch, YouTube, DailyMotion, Hitbox and more.
> - File output to MP4 or FLV.
> - GPU-based game capture for high performance game streaming.
> - DirectShow capture device support (webcams, capture cards, etc).
> - Windows 8 high speed monitor capture support.
> - Bilinear or lanczos3 resampling.

You can download OBS for macOS 10.8+ from the [official website](https://obsproject.com/download#mac). It also supports [Windows 7/8/10](https://github.com/jp9000/obs-studio/releases/download/0.15.2/OBS-Studio-0.15.2-With-Browser-Installer.exe) and [Linux](https://obsproject.com/download#linux).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**GrabberRaster**](http://b-l-a-c-k-o-p.com/GrabberRaster.html)

> Free screen grabber with live streaming: grab anything onscreen and use as a fake webcam. Desktop streaming, window grabs & more!

The screencasting requires a paid licence. Go to Window → ScreenCasting, select Grabber, then go to the app that takes a webcam as an input and select the GrabberRaster camera driver.

Comment: ManyCam will do it for free.